# jquery:BUG? Sending ajax headers will give response forbidden (Cross-Domain-Rule)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

example.comI'm using the following code:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.example.com/login.php",
                headers: {
                    "x-csrf-token": window.sailsToken
                },
                success: function(response) {
                   console.log(response);
                }
            });
```

It works well if the file is online on server.

But, on a localhost-call (htttp://localhost/myfile.html) I will get a cross-domain-error.

The php-file contents:

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```

If I delete the line "headers ..." in the ajax-call it works also well.

Is there any chance to get it to run in localhost-mode?

Comment: "a cross-domain-error" — Precisely what cross domain error do you get?

Comment: What do you mean by "localhost mode"? Are you talking about a page running on `http://localhost/` trying to access `http://www.xyz.de/login.php`? (`http://www.xyz.de/login.php` is a 404 error, is that your problem or are you using a fake URL as an example and failing to use `example.com` which is provided for the purpose?)

Comment: Yes I'm running the page http://localhost/ and I'm, using here a fake-url.

Comment: Precisely what cross domain error do you get?

Comment: its the classical cors-error-message. Here in German: Cross-Origin-Anfrage blockiert: Die Same-Origin-Regel verbietet, die externe Ressource auf http://www.b.xyz.de/login.php zu lesen. Dies kann gelöst werden, indem die Ressource auf die gleiche Domain geschoben wird oder CORS aktiviert wird.

Comment: It sounds like you are using Firefox. Does Chrome give a more informative error message? Have you examined the request in the Net tab of the developer tools / firebug to make sure it looks the way you expect?

Comment: the request is ok it works. only if i add the headers information it fails.

Comment: I would have expected that to generate a pre-flight OPTIONS request and that you weren't handling it, but you said that the request was OK.